# Animate replacing a constraint in Auto Layout

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout, core-animation

Is it possible to animate a view from one frame to another by completely changing its constraints? I don't mean changing the properties of constraints, I know that works, but if I remove and re-add completely different constraints, can Auto Layout (or whatever subsystem it actually is… Core Animation?) animate the previous frame to the new frame, or does it need to keep the same instance of a constraint in order to animate it?

Answer (score 1):

If auto layout is in place (this is a default setting in Xcode), the best way to animate a view frame is changing the constraint `constant` property and then ask Core Animation to animate the change. This is explained here: https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/uikit-dynamics-layer-constraint/

If you try disabling the constraints and animating the view `frame`, you will get a very weird behavior.

Just a note: starting from iOS 9, you should not remove or add the constraints. Instead, you have to activate and deactivate them, using the `active` property. Apple changed this to improve the layout performance.

Answer (score 0):

That would be an interesting thing to explore. In theory, you could remove all constraints from a view. UiView offers the appropriate functions for that.

You would then need to add a new set of constraints in the same scope preferably. Then call layoutifneeded (in an animation block) and then post your results.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks I'll post back here if it ends up working, but it may take me some time. I was mostly curious to know if it's theoretically possible.

Comment: The layout engine has triggers. You'd need to delete and re-create in between cycles. This way it shouldn't care about the new set of constraints.